# How to use a x86-64 docker image on arm64 with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, arm64

I use docker compose to run existing docker images behind a Traefik proxy on a Raspberry Pi. The workflow is like creating a `docker-compose.yml` file and running `docker compose up -d`.

Sometimes it is difficult to find a maintained version of a docker image for arm64, but x86-64 (or amd64) images are available. One example is Dovecot: https://hub.docker.com/r/dovecot/dovecot

**So how I can use such an image without maintaining my own version of it?**

I don't care if docker has to build the image in the background every time there comes an update, but I don't want to keep track of upstream Dockerfile changes, etc. I understand that there are cases, where this is not a trivial job (like cross-compiling binaries), but in my scenario, it is safe to assume, that all dependencies are available in arm64 and there is no compiling involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum effort is rebuilding the image on an arm64 machine or for arm64 with buildx - if you are lucky, it will work without adjustments of the dockerfile: https://github.com/dovecot/docker/blob/main/2.3.20/Dockerfile

Edit: However, simply building this image for arm64 will not be possible because it uses some Debian packages, which are not available for arm64.

But there is an image that fulfills the stated assumption (blackflysolutions/dovecot). For such an image it is as simple as **replacing the image attribute of the service with a build attribute**:

```
version: "3"

services:
  dovecot:
    build: "https://github.com/BlackflySolutions/dovecot.git#master"
    ports:
      - "143"
    volumes:
      - "~/dovecot/config:/config:rw"
      - "~/dovecot/mail:/mail:rw"
```

When running `docker compose up` it automatically downloads and builds the image based on the Dockerfile in the git repository. When updating the image it might be required to use `--build` or `--force-recreate`.

More details on how the build attribute can be customized can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/). With recent versions, it is also possible to target a sub-directory of a repository.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without manually downloading (and maintaining) the Dockerfile?

Comment: The dockerfile is already maintained by the maintainer of the repo. You only need to maintain it, if you can’t use it directly. You don’t have to download it since you can pass a URL to the build command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: For my initial example, it doesn't work because it uses an extra Dovecot repository which has no arm64 binaries. But the for the even more popular blackflysolutions/dovecot the solution works. Do you mind if I edit your answer to add an example docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Feel free to edit or add your own answer